# ¿Cómo guardar dos objetos en mysql a traves del metodo post?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, rest, post

Estoy intentando guardar dos objetos a la vez como los siguientes.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "kion",
        "alumno": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "miel",
        "alumno": 3
    }
]
```

El alumno 3 tendria 2 mascotas kion y miel.
No me da error al insertarlos, pero cuando hago un get de ellos me sale el nombre como "undefined".
El método post que tengo definido es el siguiente:

```
// Añadir alumno
app.post("/api/alumno/:id/mascota", function(req, res){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO mascota (nombre, alumno)" + 
    " VALUES ('"+ req.body.nombre +"','"+ req.params.id +"')";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, resultado){
        if(err){
            res.status(403).json("Error de sentencia SQL: " + err); 
            return;
        }
        res.status(201).json(resultado);
    });
});
```

Lo que hace es asociar el alumno a las mascotas que tiene. Si solo añado 1 mascota si que funciona correctamente, pero si meto dos a la vez no, ya que el nombre me sale undefined, (lo estoy comprobando con Postman). ¿Como podría solucionarlo?
(El id en la base de datos ya esta puesto como incremental. )

Comment: ¿cuál es el método get? ¿en la base de datos los graba correctamente?

Comment: El método get lo tengo asi, y si que me funciona bien.
// Mascotas de un alumno
app.get("/api/alumno/:id/mascota", function (req, res){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM mascota WHERE mascota.alumno = '" + req.params.id + "'";
    connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            res.status(404).json("Error de sentencia SQL: " + err); 
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json(result);
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problema

`req.params.id` al ser pasado en el URI siempre va a estar definido, pero `req.body.nombre` si pasas un objeto solo

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "miel",
    "alumno": 3
}
```

será "miel", pero si pasas un arreglo, el arreglo no tiene la propiedad nombre, por eso verás undefined.
Por eso es importante que no importa si actualizas una o 10 mascotas, siempre el cuerpo sea consistente, siempre un arreglo, o siempre un objeto. Intentemos con un arreglo que veo que es lo que has propuesto.

## Solución

Al pasar un arreglo en el body, debes ir iterándolo para extraer los objetos que contienen la información. Por ejemplo, si envío en el body el arreglo de tu problema original

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "kion",
        "alumno": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "miel",
        "alumno": 3
    }
]
```

Y luego en el endpoint

```
for (row of req.body) {
    console.log(row);
}
```

Obtendré por consola cada objeto, con lo cual ahí si puedo acceder a sus propiedades.

Si tengo que enviar un solo objeto, también lo debo hacer como un arreglo

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "otro",
        "alumno": 3
    }
]
```

Por otra parte, para armar un INSERT con múltiples valores, debería obtener algo así:

```
"INSERT INTO mascota (nombre, alumno) VALUES (kion, 11),(miel, 11)"
```

Con lo cual debo armar las tuplas que van después de `VALUES` a medida que recorro el arreglo del body del request.

## Código funcionando

```
// Añadir alumno
app.post("/api/alumno/:id/mascota", function(req, res){
    let comma = '';
    let values = '';
    for (row of req.body) {
        values += `${comma}('${row.nombre}', '${req.params.id}')`;
        comma = ',';
    }        
    let sql = `INSERT INTO mascota (nombre, alumno) VALUES ${values}`;
    connection.query(sql, function(err, resultado){
        if(err){
            res.status(403).json("Error de sentencia SQL: " + err); 
            return;
        }
        res.status(201).json(resultado);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola, he comprobado el código y me da este error:   "Error de sentencia SQL: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'kion' in 'field list'"
He impreso la sentencia sql y me esto, INSERT INTO patologias (nombre, paciente) VALUES (kion, 3),(miel, 3). Ya no se que es lo que falla

Comment: SOLUCIONADO y muchas gracias por la ayuda. Faltaba añadir comillas en los valores, de esta forma:
let comillas = "'";
values += `${comma}(${comillas}${row.nombre}${comillas}, ${comillas}${req.params.id}${comillas})`;

Comment: Gracias, editaré la respuesta.